# How to recognize the phone state whether the out going call received or not

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I need to recognize the broadcast event when the

1. Out going call has started,
2. An out going call received at the receiver end and
3. An out going call hang up

I can able to get the Incoming call events but not out going call events.

Here is my code, please figure out my problem and give a solution.

Thanks in Advance

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // We listen to two intents. The new outgoing call only tells us of an
    // outgoing call. We use it to get the number.
    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras()
                .getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    } else {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras()
                .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras()
                .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code help you to get net work status code in onCreate

```
 StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

create an inner class for listening state of phone.

```
class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        System.out.println("call Activity off hook");
        LockScreenActivity.this.finish();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        break;
}
}
};
```

Set permission in manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Out going call has started,

- You can recognise the whether outgoing call is started on not using below code

  ```
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              isIncoming = true;
              callStartTime = new Date();
              savedNumber = number;
              onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, callStartTime);
              break;
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
              //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
              if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                  isIncoming = false;
                  callStartTime = new Date();
                  startRecording(context,"_Out_",number);
                  onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
              }
              else
              {
                  isIncoming = true;
                  callStartTime = new Date();
                  startRecording(context,"_In_",savedNumber);
                  onIncomingCallAnswered(context, number, callStartTime);
              }

              break;
  ```

2) An out going call received at the receiver end and
3) An out going call hang up

However you can not recognise call is picked up by other end by using any direct api as android does not provide any direct api to detect that.